# Error with android emulator, not loading app and not enough memory

Tags: android, emulation

Just recently my emulator has started up with out launching the app and came up with the error below. Tried several things to get it to work but still get the error.

Can anyone help?

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

click ok and application will install. this error is not an issue your emulator just run out of memory.

Comment: Tried that does not work, log comes up with the following.

Comment: /Users/d867mak/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-05-13 at 12.15.29.png

Comment: create new emulator and increase the memory size of that and run your app on new emulator